# HTML CSS Increase Stroke/Thickness for SVG Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, google-material-icons

Just learning html,
How do I increase the stroke width of a SVG google icon?
This does not seem to be working.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>


<i class="material-icons" style="stroke-width: 100"> arrow_forward</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you are trying to increase the size of the SVG rather than change the size of an individual stroke. If that is the case, then you will more likely want to use `font-size` instead. This will resize the whole icon.

```
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 100px;"> arrow_forward</i>
```

Comment: I want to change the size of the actual strokes, not the size, thanks

Comment: I think I understand now. You many want to try something link this `<i class="material-icons" style="-webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;"> arrow_forward</i>`. From the developers notes, it looks like it does not work in Internet Explorer however.

Answer (score 0):

The stroke-width property defines the thickness of a line, text or outline of an element inside the svg tag.

Increasing the font-size will fix it.

Comment: Increase the font-size.

Comment: can you write the full working code above? I can send points, thanks

Comment: <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 100px"> arrow_forward</i>

Comment: I want to change the size of the actual strokes, not the size, thanks

Comment: Download the google icon as a svg, and add stroke property.

Comment: or go to google icon site(https://icons8.com/icons/set/google) > search for right arrow > click the icon > change stroke > Done > click embed HTML > It will gives the svg with the updates stroke value.